# Saved Search Formula to show Payment Status

Tags: search, text, formula

I need to put in a saved search a column saying if the specific Sales Order was fully paid, if yes, the column needs to say "Paid" if not "Waiting for Payment".

This was the formula that I did:

CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.status} ='PAID IN FULL' THEN 'PAID' ELSE 'WAITING FOR PAYMENT' END

But it gives me the message: ERROR: Invalid Expression

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

=if(Status="PAID IN FULL","Paid","Waiting For Payment")